# Unresolved reference error in kotlin (bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am trying to implement a navigation bar in kotlin and im getting a unresolved reference on  bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener apparently the bottom_navigation is an unresolved reference. I checked everyhting and cant fix it. I am not sure what im missing out on.

Any help is greatly appreciated thnxs.

[The code below is my MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct9Ac.jpg)

Comment: Please also post your xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply replace `bottom_navigation` with

```
findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)
    .setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {...}
```